# Sort a matrix according to one row in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, algebra

I'm fairly new to Mathematica and I've come across a probably stupid problem.

I have a matrix  `{{1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2},{-1,0,1,-2,-1,0,1,2}}` and I would like to sort the second row but also that the positions of the elements of the first row are sorted at the same time.

Thus, the array would become `{{2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2},{-2,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,2}}`. I hope is it clear. Do you know how I could proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {-1, 0, 1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2}}
```

then

```
{list[[1]][[Ordering[list[[2]]]]], Sort[list[[2]]]}
```

gives the output you are looking for.

For future reference, you might want to think about posting *Mathematica*  questions at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
SortBy[Transpose[data],Last]//Transpose
```

> {{2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {-2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}}